# Azure SQL database not found or inaccessible problem

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I can access Azure SQL database with pyodbc at home to write data. But the same code does not work at work. I set the Azure server firewall to accept all IPs 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. Could you let me know about potential problems? I already checked other references but none worked for me (e.g. setting up ODBC driver, using tcp for the server)... Can my workplace network block this in someway?

Thank you!

Comment: Let us see which code is not working. Without overlooking that code it would be hard and inappropriate to give an advice.

Comment: "does not work" is a completely useless problem description. Describe how it does not work. Retrieve an error message and post it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid if it is useless, move on. there are many people willing to help without giving us this attitude.

Comment: Please for your next question - post the actual error message

Comment: Nick could have been a bit softer with his approach but he's correct in that without an exact error we're basically throwing crap against the wall and seeing what sticks. The actual error message is a huge help to us to try to help you out. This could be a database configuration issue to a corporate firewall issue or many others in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible that the corporate firewall is not permitting external access on Port 1433.

Azure SQL Database ONLY listens externally on Port 1433.  If you are connecting from another Azure service then it is a different set of ports that will be used.

Check with your network team whether they have a rule blocking this access.

Also try connecting using SQL Management Studio from your corporate network - if this fails then it is very likely that port 1433 is blocked outbound on your network.